# Amazon MWS Fulfillment Feed - Error Response after processing "one or more items are invalid"

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

i submit a fulfillment feed and always get the same error (after requesting GetFeedSubmissionResult), my acknowledgement feed works and i can see the updated MerchantOrderId in Sellercentral.

The feed xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>***</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OrderFulfillment>
       <AmazonOrderID>302-7735***-***</AmazonOrderID>
       <MerchantFulfillmentID>121625</MerchantFulfillmentID>
       <FulfillmentDate>2015-12-23T09:03:18+0100</FulfillmentDate>
       <FulfillmentData>
           <CarrierCode>DHL</CarrierCode>
           <ShipperTrackingNumber>1667***</ShipperTrackingNumber>
       </FulfillmentData>
    <Item>
        <AmazonOrderItemCode>52269***</AmazonOrderItemCode>
        <MerchantFulfillmentItemID>371064</MerchantFulfillmentItemID>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </Item>
    </OrderFulfillment>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

The Response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>***</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <ProcessingReport>
        <DocumentTransactionID>5004***</DocumentTransactionID>
        <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
        <ProcessingSummary>
            <MessagesProcessed>1</MessagesProcessed>
            <MessagesSuccessful>0</MessagesSuccessful>
            <MessagesWithError>1</MessagesWithError>
            <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
        </ProcessingSummary>
        <Result>
            <MessageID>1</MessageID>
            <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
            <ResultMessageCode>25</ResultMessageCode>
            <ResultDescription>We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed.</ResultDescription>
        </Result>
    </ProcessingReport>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

I tried with and without the `<Item></Item>` Part, i tried without `<MerchantFulfillmentID>`, i tried `<MerchantOrderId>` instead of `<AmazonOrderId>`...
I also tried `<ShippingMethod>Standard</ShippingMethod>` but i dont know if "Standard" is a valid value.

So can anyone point me in the right direction - what am i missing here?
Is there any neccessary action before the fulfillment feed that i might have missed? Is the `<MerchantFulfillmentID>` just a value i can choose here or does it have to be set in some feed before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured it out - the Date Format seems to be the problem.

In the documentation i only find "ISO8601" but in PHP `DateTime::ISO8601` will give a string like `2015-12-23T09:03:18+0100` while amazon seems only to accept `+01:00` instead of `+0100`. In PHP this is `DateTime::ATOM` and not `ISO8601`.

So in PHP Code you should use `$date->format(DateTime::ATOM)` in the feeds.